# IBM MQ Issue - Error: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2035: FAILED: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am writing simple python code to put message in the IBM MQ. The code works fine, except when i add *'pcf = pymqi.PCFExecute(qmgr)'* line it throws an error *'Error: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2035: FAILED: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED'*

Suggest the solution for the same.

```
import pymqi

queue_manager = 'QM1'
channel = 'DEV.APP.SVRCONN'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = '1414'
queue_name = 'DEV.QUEUE.1'
message = 'Hello from Python!'
conn_info = f'{host}({port})'
user = 'app'
password = 'qwerty'

try:
    # Establish connection to the queue manager
    qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info, user, password)

    # Create a PCFExecute object
    pcf = pymqi.PCFExecute(qmgr)

    # Open the queue
    queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)

    # Put a message to the queue
    queue.put(message)

    # Close the queue
    queue.close()

except pymqi.MQMIError as e:
    print(f'Error: {e}')
```

Comment: Why are you adding `pcf = pymqi.PCFExecute(qmgr)`?  It doesn't look like it serves any purpose with the rest of the code.

Comment: The use case is to get the message id and time stamp from the message header.

Comment: And how does `PCFExecute` help you to get the message ID and time stamp from the message?

Comment: Well let's say this way - There are other commands for which i would need 'pcf' object.

Comment: It would appear that you are missing some authorisations needed to use `PCFExecute`. From memory it probably opens the command server queue and a model queue to create a replyQ. Look in the Queue Manager AMQERR01.LOG for the error messages that show what permissions you are missing and grant them. You may have to do a few iterations until all the missing ones are reported and you can rectify them all.

Comment: It worked after setting authority: 

 ```SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) PRINCIPAL('app') AUTHADD(ALL)``` and
```SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PROFILE('**') PRINCIPAL('app') AUTHADD(ALL)```

Comment: Wow, by issuing those 2 AUTHREC commands, you just gave "god authority" to "app" UserId for the ENTIRE queue manager. Any security team would not recommend that. You should have used ALLMQI for AUTHADD and specifically listed the queues the application is going to access.

Comment: Thanks for adding comment @Roger.  I will be more specific in prod while giving permissions.

Comment: You should set it up right in non prod so you do not have surprises in prod related to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved after providing the right permission to the user.
These permissions are not recommended for prod environment.

```
SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) PRINCIPAL('app') AUTHADD(ALL)
SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PROFILE('**') PRINCIPAL('app') AUTHADD(ALL)
SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(TOPIC) PROFILE('**') PRINCIPAL('app') AUTHADD(ALL)
```